# View and edit roles in Portal for ArcGIS and ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.4, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I am using Portal for ArcGIS 10.4.1 and web app builder developer edition to build application. My application is ready but now I have to create two groups: One group have a view capability only and other can have edit capabilities in the same application.

Comment: Dear Rodri,I have build an application using arcgis web app builder which is using web map hosted on arcgis portal 10.4.1 and features layer from arcgis server.My web application contains editing/updating and viewing.My question is i want to create groups login for users.One group of users can edit/update features and other can view only.

Comment: i have created two groups one named as Map view and Edit view.I have added the logins with view capability custom role to map view and other with full role(editing).still It is not working both groups are editing the web application.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional details.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing the capabilities in the custom role.  Ensure you have the following capability disabled for the role which you want users to not have editing rights.

[image]

Add the users to the relevant role.